# PKPaymentRequest conditionally invalid

Tags: braintree, applepay, passkit

When creating a paymentRequest, configuring as such works:

```
let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
...
paymentRequest.countryCode = "US";
paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD";
...
```

However, configuring by using "UK" and "GBP" doesnt work. Im probably missing something, is there a ruleset somewhere? Im simply trying to make a payment in pounds.

More specifically (code from Braintree ) :

```
// Example: Promote PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController to optional so that we can verify
// that our paymentRequest is valid. Otherwise, an invalid paymentRequest would crash our app.

 if let vca = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest) as PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?
 {
    ...logic...
 } else {
    ->this is what i get when using pounds or anything else<-
 }
```

Comment: Is there an error message that populates when you try to make a payment in pounds that you can share? Any information that you can provide to help us replicate your issue would be helpful.

Comment: i added some more code that might help but it probably wont. I never get to see the apple pay window if that wasnt clear so i never get to actually make the payment. The PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController just wont initialize when using GBP+UK

Comment: Is your sandbox or production account [configured to accept GBP payments](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/try-it-out#testing-currencies)? you can see this by logging into the Control Panel and navigating to Settings > Merchant Accounts, which will show a full list of currencies for your account.

Comment: Given that PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController is part of PassKit it looks like i shouldnt matter. This at this point seems more like a PassKit problem and less of a Braintree issue.